What is this movie set during the American Civil War or post Civil War?
I'm thinking of a movie that was either set during the American Civil War or the post Civil War era. This movie could be a western....I just can't pinpoint where it came from. Could also be a TV show. This was created in at least the late 90's.
In one scene, some of the main characters enter a bar or restaurant and there are two groups of men singing. One group is either Confederate soldiers/veterans and the other group is Union soldiers/veterans. The two groups keep singing each side's anthem...for instance the southerners keep singing "Way Down South in Dixie" - or something along those lines. I believe they go on like this for some time.

Do you know when you saw this, approx how old the movie was, any recognizable actors, etc? Any additional info will help.

Is this black and white or color? Where did you see this movie?

I believe this might be Dodge City, a 1939 film starring Errol Flynn. 
This movie was set soon after the American Civil War where Errol Flynn's character had fought for Confederacy. In this specific scene a group of showgirls begin singing 'Marching Through Georgia', soon the former Union soldiers join in. Part way through the song a group of Confederate war veterans tries to drown the song out with the song 'Dixie', this eventually leads to a brawl.




No that's not it! It's a more modern movie (at least late 90s). I'm trying to think of who was in it but drawing a blank.... The concept is similar to this scend from Dodge City though! Thanks for trying.

@Brulia where did you see this? I assume it was on tv, any idea which channel?
